# Cfitsio Error in VC ++ 6.0

Tags: c++, class, templates, visual-c++

I am interfacing two software among which one is using sfits library for processing the fits images , when compile the program it shows error in XLOCALE file,which recides in vc98 / include folder , im using vc 6.0 with XP ,

> error : error C2955: 'ctype' : use
>   of class template requires template
>   argument list C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio6\VC98\INCLUDE\xlocale(513) :
>   see declaration of 'ctype'
>
> error is pointing to line  :  int
>   fits_get_compression_type(fitsfile
>   *fptr, int *ctype, int *status);

and in XLOCALE file its pointing to :

```
template<class _E>
        class ctype : public ctype_base {
public:
        typedef _E char_type;

        ctype(const _Locinfo& _Lobj, size_t _R = 0)
                : ctype_base(_R) {_Init(_Lobj); }
        static size_t __cdecl _Getcat()
                {return (_LC_CTYPE); }
_PROTECTED:
        virtual ~ctype()
                {if (_Ctype._Delfl)
                        free((void *)_Ctype._Table); }
protected:


        virtual const _E *do_narrow(const _E *_F, const _E *_L,
                char, char *_V) const
                {for (; _F != _L; ++_F, ++_V)
                        *_V = (char)_NARROW(_E, *_F);
                return (_F); }
private:
        _Locinfo::_Ctypevec _Ctype;
        };
template<class _E>
        locale::id ctype<_E>::id;
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

ctype is a template for a type, not a type itself. Your parameter would have to be `ctype<char>` or `ctype<wchar_t>` depending on what character type you use.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir for your reply , But can you please elaborate it as I am not getting where to do correction...In calling function ctype is mentioned as (int *ctype)...thnx in anticipation.

Comment: Ah, I got the impression you tried to use the class template ctype, and so did obviously the compiler. But you don't, you just use the same name. Is there perhaps a `using namespace std` anywhere near this code? That could possibly confuse the compiler. VC6 isn't that reliable...

Comment: thanx for reply ,And  I already checked for using nqmespace std , but its not anywhere on that file..

Comment: I recall that VC6 had major issues with name lookup. And really I wouldn't bother. Just rename the variable, or (even better) upgrade to a recent VC version.